# How to find all possible combinations of radio buttons selection in js?

Tags: javascript

I have radiobuttons in radio groups. For example:

```
<!-- A -->
<div>A</div>
<input type="radio" name="A" value="A1" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="A" value="A2" />
<input type="radio" name="A" value="A3" />

<!-- B -->
<div>B</div>    
<input type="radio" name="B" value="B1" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="B" value="B2" />
```

It is required to have one selected radio button in each group. I need to find all possible combinations of radio buttons selection. In my example it is:

```
A=A1, B=B1
A=A2, B=B1
A=A3, B=B1,
A=A1, B=B2, 
A=A2, B=B2,
A=A3, B=B2
```

How can I do it in JS?

Comment: Why on earth would you need that ?

Comment: Our designer will draw a picture for each combination, so I should give him the list of all possible combinations

Comment: Why on earth would he do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all the `A` radio buttons, each time looping (in another loop) through `B`s.

```
var A = document.querySelectorAll("[name='A']");
var B = document.querySelectorAll("[name='B']");
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
        console.log('A= ' + A[i].value + ', ' + 'B= ' + B[j].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wrote simple example, but there can be C, D, E etc

Comment: You have the main method here, you can tweak it a little bit to make it more dynamic...

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose? What are you going to do with those combinations?

If you just want to find all of the possible combinations, then this should do it:

```
function combinations(groups, numPerGroup){ //array of groups, number per group
  var com = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < numPerGroup; j++){
      com += groups[i] + i + "\n";
    }
  }
    return com;
}
```